# SP2013 Validation - If NULL, show N/A

Tags: list, validation, validation-list-items

I have a list that I'd like to do some validation on, but I'm having trouble with the exact syntax of the idea (if it's even possible).  The idea is that if a list item's field is NULL, then the particular field will populate with "N/A" when the item is saved in the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Columns are"blank" rather than NULL. Try this in a Calculated Column if you want to display the message in another column.

.   =IF( ISBLANK( [yourColumn] ), "n/a", "")

If the column is a Single line of Text column, then you could set the default to "n/a".

You can add a validation if you want to prevent the save when blank.

Comment: I'd rather display the "N/A" message in the same column, but let's see how this goes.  Of course, using the N/A as default on CHOICE columns works, too (although it took me a minute to consider that option.  It's Friday, and my brain is certainly acting like it).  I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same column default calculated values wont work as the formula can not circular reference the column which contains it.

However, this can be achieved a number of ways, depending if you simply wish to display the N/A for cosmetic purposes in the UI, or if you actually require the underlying value to be set.

For display only :-

- Client Side Rendering (CSR) and / or JSLink - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views
- Custom JavaScript either added to masterpage, page layout or via a Content Editor / HTML form editor webpart.

Or if you actually need to set the underlying value :-

- Column default value set to N/A - This trade off will actually set the value of the column the first time a user leaves it blank, but if a user changes to something else and then sets it to a blank value again it will no longer be N/A
- Workflow / Event Receiver or other external programmatic process (Timer job) to set the value to N/A whenever it is detected as being blank